# ADF Reduce Queue Time for Copy Activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy a backup file that is provided from a HTTP source, the download URL is only valid for 60 seconds and the Copy step is timing out before it can complete (timeout set to 1 min 1 second). It will complete on occasion but is very inconsistent. When it completes the step queues for around 40 seconds, other times it will be queued for over a minute and the link has expired when it eventually gets to downloading the file. It is one zipped JSON file that is being downloaded, less than 100 KB.

Both Source and Sink datasets are using a Managed VNet IR we have created (must be used on Sink due to company policy), using the AutoResolve IR on the Source and it takes even longer queueing.

I've tried all variations of 'Max concurrent connections', 'DIU' and 'Degree of copy parallelism' in the Copy activity I can think of and none seem to have any effect. It appears to be random if the queue time is short enough for the download to succeed.

Is there any way to speed up the queue process to try and get more consistent successful downloads?

Comment: Welcome! This delay could be related to source-side performance. Have you tried downloading outside of ADF, to get an objective measurement? I would suggest starting there. Given that you've tweaked the various performance-specific ADF settings, I'm not sure what else could be done ADF-side.

Comment: Thank you!
Sadly I've already tried that, sorry I forgot to mention. The download is immediate when I try directly in a web browser using the download URL. When ADF is successful the Transfer says it took 2 seconds, it's just the queueing before it gets to that point causing my issue.
I was afraid there wasn't much that could be done but hopeful that I'd missed something. Currently I have the steps that get a new download URL and the Copy in an Until activity that keeps trying for up to an hour, it has gone the full hour without successfully downloading the file before.

Answer (score 0):

> Both Source and Sink datasets are using a Managed VNet IR we have
> created (must be used on Sink due to company policy), using the
> AutoResolve IR on the Source and it takes even longer queueing.

This is pretty much confusing. If your Source and Sink are in **Managed VNet**, your IR also should be in same **Managed VNet** for better security and performance.

As per [this official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#activity-execution-time-varies-using-azure-ir-vs-azure-vnet-ir):

> By design, Managed VNet IR takes longer queue time than Azure IR as we
> are not reserving one compute node per service instance, so there is a
> warm up for each copy activity to start, and it occurs primarily on
> VNet join rather than Azure IR.

Since there is no reserved node, there isn't any possible way to speed up the queue process.